# Check all / uncheck all Checkbox in looping statement

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, checkbox

i have a problem with my program. Here's my snippet code.

Here's the Javascript/Jquery code.

```
<script language='javascript'>

///SELECTING CHECKBOXES////
$(function(){

// add multiple select / deselect functionality
$("#selectall").click(function () {
      $('.case').attr('checked', this.checked);
});

// if all checkbox are selected, check the selectall checkbox
// and viceversa
$(".case").click(function(){

    if($(".case").length == $(".case:checked").length) {
        $("#selectall").attr("checked", "checked");
    } else {
        $("#selectall").removeAttr("checked");
    }

});
});
</script>
```

---

And here's the code where i will integrate that javascript.

```
 <h2>Quotation ID</h2>
            <?php

        $select_orders = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM tblorder WHERE project_id = '$project_id' GROUP BY quotation_id") OR DIE (mysql_error());
        while ($row2=mysql_fetch_array($select_orders)){
            $quote_id = $row2['quotation_id'];


            ?>
        <h3 class="expand"><?php echo $quote_id; ?></h3>
        <div class="collapse">
            <table align='center' border='1' class='display'>
                <thead>
                    <th><input type='checkbox' onclick='checkall()' id='selectall'/></th>
                    <th>Product Type</th>
                    <th width='20px'>Product type code</th>
                    <th width='20px'>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Width</th>
                    <th>Height</th>
                    <th>Total Sub.</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php
                $tots_tots = 0;
                $tots_subs = 0;
                $select_orders2 = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM tblorder WHERE project_id = '$project_id' AND quotation_id = '$quote_id'") OR DIE (mysql_error());
                    while ($row3=mysql_fetch_array($select_orders2)){
                        $idd = $row3['id'];
                        $project_id2 = $row3['project_id'];
                        $order_id = $row3['quotation_id'];
                        $prod_type = $row3['prod_type'];
                        $prod_type_code = $row3['prod_type_code'];
                        $qty = $row3['qty'];
                        $width = $row3['width'];
                        $height = $row3['height'];
                        $tot_sub = $row3['total_subs'];

                        $tots_subs += $tot_sub;

                echo "<tr bgcolor='".$colors[$c++ % 2]."' align='center'>";
                    echo "<td>
                    <input type='hidden' name='project_name' value='$project_name'>
                    <input type='checkbox' name='check_ptc[]' value='$prod_type_code' style='display:none;' checked>
                    <input type='checkbox' class='case' name='checkbox[]' value='".$idd."'></td>";
                    echo "
                            <input type='hidden' name='project_id[]' value='$project_id2'>
                        </td>";
                    echo "<td>".$prod_type."
                            <input type='hidden' name='quotation_id[]' value='$order_id'>
                            <input type='hidden' name='prod_type[]' value='$prod_type'>
                        </td>";
                    echo "<td>".$prod_type_code."
                            <input type='hidden' name='prod_type_code[]' value='$prod_type_code'>
                        </td>";
                    echo "<td>".$qty."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$width."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$height."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$tot_sub."</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                }
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
                        <td>
                            <strong><b>Total:</b></strong>";
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td>
                            <font color='#900'><u><b>$tots_subs</b></u></font>
                        </td>";

                echo "</tr>";
                ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <?php 
        }
        ?>
```

---

Since the table is in the loop. the problem is when the first table appear. and click the first header checkbox it will check all the checkbox in other table. which i dont want to happen. the one i am looking for is if there is a way i can also iterate the ID of the checkbox and its class. or there's any other way to do what i want to happen.

---

[image: Here's a sample screen shot of the code output will be..]

As you can see. those 3 tables have there own checkbox header where i want to be the check all inside there tables. what would be your smart idea how can i do that.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You can replace `if($(".case").length == $(".case:checked").length)` with a shorter version: `if(!$(".case:not(:checked)").length)`

Comment: In this element, remove the inline onclick handler! jquery is doing that for you! `<input type='checkbox' onclick='checkall()' id='selectall'/>`

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this.

```
$('.allcb').on('click', function(){
    var childClass = $(this).attr('data-child');
    $('.'+childClass+'').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/NxBJg/)

**UPDATE**

Just apply the class `allcb` to the main check-boxes and to the child check-boxes apply the class named as `chk`. This should fit your needs. Here is the updated 
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/NxBJg/1/)

Comment: Due my table is inside the loop. the data-child and class allcb should also iterate.. i tried this code but it didn't work :(

Comment: sir what would be the use function parent() x4? sorry but im new to jquery :D why is that you have 4 parent()? is this for the generated four times?

Comment: I have used `parent()`x4 because `.allcb` was placed under `th` tag. So its first parent will be `th` than `th` is child of `tr` and than `tr` is child of `thead` and than `thead` is child of `table`

Comment: You explain it much well than the docu. :D

Comment: Did it solve your problem? Or are you still facing any difficulties in implementing that code?

Comment: yeah sir actually it didn't check the checkbox childs. i don't know why.. :( is div's also should indicate in parent()?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37140/discussion-between-khawer-zeshan-and-user2593560)

Answer (score 1):

use .prop

```
$(function () {
    var $cases = $('.case');

    // add multiple select / deselect functionality
    var $all = $("#selectall").click(function () {
        $$cases.prop('checked', this.checked);
    });

    // if all checkbox are selected, check the selectall checkbox
    // and viceversa
    $cases.click(function () {
        $all.prop("checked", $cases.filter(":not(:checked)").length) != 0);
    });
});
```

Comment: using this code is essential.. but in my case this is not what i wanted. when i integrate this code to my code.. it has the same problem. when the first table appear.. and toggle the checkall checkbox other tables are also checked. which is not my plan. the idea of @Khawer Zeshan is alike. but no luck to mine. :(

Answer (score 1):

try this php code instead script 
//check-all / uncheck-all  checkbox.

```
<a onclick="$(this).parent().find(':checkbox').attr('checked', true);"><?php echo $text_select_all; ?></a>/<a onclick="$(this).parent().find(':checkbox').attr('checked', false);"><?php echo $text_unselect_all; ?></a>
```